# Spring REST - after longer Idle time the first calls take very long time (5-10 seconds)

Tags: java, spring, timeout, delay

We are running microservices on spring boot (with embedded tomcat) and spring cloud. It means service discovery, regular health checks and services that are responding to these health checks, ... We have also spring boot admin server for monitoring and we can see that all services are running ok. Currently running only on test environment...

Some of our microservices are called quite rarely (let's assume once per two days) however there are still regular health checks. When REST api of these services is called after so long idle time the first request takes very long time to process. It of course causes opening circuit breakers in request chains and errors... I see this behavior also when calling different endpoints using spring boot admin (Theads list, Metrics).

As a summary I have seen this behavior in calls on spring boot admim metrics, threads info, environment info or calls where database is called using Hikari data source or where aservice tried to send email through smtp server

My questions are:
Is it something related to setting of embedded server and its thread pool?
Or should I dive deep into other thread pools and connection pools touched by these requests?
Any ideas for diagnostics?

Many thanks

Comment: I've encountered a similar problem in a private project... it does seem, that spring lazily initializes the REST-Components, which explains the longer wait time when you first call the resource

Comment: Yes you are right, there are some lazy initializations but this is not what I mean. This is about calls that were already done a few times after server start and then after long idle time were called again (and took very long time)

Comment: Hi Lukas, did you ever come to a solution here outside of the heap space. Have the same issue myself

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that there was not enough RAM to cover whole heap of those applications ... wrong setting applied to multiple virtual machines. Part of the heap was actually swapping. The problem dissapeared when heap and RAM sizes were fixed.